# Delphi 2009: "Class not found" when using component package

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a package of custom components that compiles and installs installs with no problems.  The source files for the package are in my library path, as is the location of the resulting bpl files.  After installing, the package and components correctly appear in the Design packages list.  They do not appear in the Tool Palette, however.

However, any time I open a form that contains one of the components, I get a class not found error, and the dfm won't open.  The project will compile fine, and I can view all pas files, but the form won't show in the designer.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I get the components to show properly in the form designer?

Here's my registration code for the components:

```
  RegisterComponents('QuoteSystem', [
    TFnpLabelNumericEdit,
      TPBxCheckBox,
      TPBxCheckBoxSub,
      TPBxComboBoxSub,
      TPBxListBoxSub,
      TPBxRadioItemSub,
      TFnpNumericEdit,
      TQGlobals,
      TPBItem,
      TPBxCheckListBox,
      TPBxCheckListBox,
      TPBxComboBox,
      TPBxDateEdit,
      TPBxDescList,
      TPBxEdit,
      TpbxInteger,
      TPBxLabel,
      TPBxLabeledEdit,
      TPBxLabelNumericEdit,
      TPBxListBox,
      TPBxMemo,
      TPBxNumericEdit,
      TPBxQuoteElement,
      TPBxRadioGroup,
      TPBxRadioItem,
      TPBxRichEdit,
      TPBxSpinEdit,
      TpbxSummaryGlobals,
      TAlignEdit
]);
```

Comment: Do you have the dcu files in your searchpath?

Comment: They're in Delphi's library path...

Comment: Does the program start correctly after compilation? Review the .dfm file in a stand alone text editor for any anomalies.

Comment: It starts and runs fine...the components don't even show up in the Tool Palette.

Comment: If the components don't show on the palette then the design time package registration did not go well. It may be related to a different Delphi version settings in some configuration file. And some defines may mess the code very bad if they do not know the Delphi in the version currently being used.

Comment: I have defines based on the delphi version number.  As to a configuration file, I'm not sure exactly which file you're speaking of...

Comment: When it comes to defines for Delphi 2009 you should have some lines like {$IFDEF VER200} otherwise you may have some code excluded. Most often updating the closest define section to 200 helps.  Configuration files are usually *.inc files with some more conditionals.

Comment: @croceldon Please could you post the full code of your routine named `Register`, the one that calls `RegisterComponents`.

Answer (score 2):

The typical mistake for this to happen is writing `Register` in either the interface section or implementation section in lowercase or any other case than the correct one.

Wrong:

```
procedure register;

implementation

procedure register;
```

Correct:

```
procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
```

Comment: That's not the case here.  I have Register capitalized properly.

Comment: Still a good tip though. It has once costed me several hours to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your components like this

```
RegisterComponents ('Custom', [TMyCustomComp1, TMyCustomComp2]);
```

otherwise the IDE will not be able to create the components in the form designer.

Answer (score 0):

Convince yourself having added the unit which contains the registering code to the `contains` section in the package file / project source.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean.  I have a runtime package - qteSys.bpl, and a design package - qteSysDesign.bpl.  The registration code is contained in the design package.

Comment: Well, typically the registration code (i.e. `procedure Register`) is in a separate unit. One could easily forget to add that unit to the `contains` section of your `.DPK` project source file.